# How to avoid unwanted double vertical lines in multicolumn table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Hello I am having some issues with creating a simple multicolumn table. As you can see in the screenshot below, there are some vertical lines that appear double.

[image: screenshot]

Here's my code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption[Estadísticos de error y concordancia para el caso C46]{Estadísticos de error (RMSE y MAE) e índice de concordancia ($d$) entre las series de superficie libre predicha y observada para el caso C46.}

\begin{tabular}{l|cccc|rrrrr}
\toprule
  &\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{t=6s} & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{t=30s} \\
                                 & z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FE}} & z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FV}}  & $\eta $\textsubscript{FE}      & $\eta $\textsubscript{FV}                                & z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FE}} & z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FV}}  & $\eta $\textsubscript{FE}      & $\eta $\textsubscript{FV}  \\

\midrule
$\mathrm{RMSE}\,\mathrm{[cm]}$ & $1.2$   & $1.1$   & $1.4$   & $1.3$ & $1.2$   & $1.1$   & $1.4$   & $1.3$    \\
$ \mathrm{BSS}\,\mathrm{[-]}$ & $4.6$   & $5.3$   & $6.7$   & $6.6$ & $1.2$   & $1.1$   & $1.4$   & $1.3$    \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: you have specified two lines, `\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{t=6s}` should be `\multicolumn{4}{c|}{t=6s}` and `\multicolumn{4}{|c}{t=30s}` should be `\multicolumn{4}{c}{t=30s}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not bother with vertical lines but design table without them (and never mix them with rules from `booktabs` package):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption[Estadísticos de error y concordancia para el caso C46]{Estadísticos de error (RMSE y MAE) e índice de concordancia ($d$) entre las series de superficie libre predicha y observada para el caso C46.}

\begin{tabular}{l *{8}{c}}
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{$t=\SI{6}{s}$} 
        &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{$t=\SI{30}{s}$} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
    &   z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FE}} 
        &   z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FV}}  
            &   $\eta $\textsubscript{FE}      
                &   $\eta$\textsubscript{FV}                                
                    &   z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FE}} 
                        &   z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FV}}  
                            &   $\eta$\textsubscript{FE}      
                                &   $\eta$\textsubscript{FV}  \\

    \midrule
$\mathrm{RMSE}$ \[cm] & $1.2$   & $1.1$   & $1.4$   & $1.3$ & $1.2$   & $1.1$   & $1.4$   & $1.3$    \\
$ \mathrm{BSS}$ $[-]$ & $4.6$   & $5.3$   & $6.7$   & $6.6$ & $1.2$   & $1.1$   & $1.4$   & $1.3$    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
In case when you like to have wide table you can increase separation between column from default value 6pt for example to 9pt:

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{9pt}
```

or in case when table width had to be equal text width, then is handy to use ˙tabular*`` environment with ` @{\extracolsep{\fill} option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption[Estadísticos de error $y$ concordancia para el caso C46]
        {Estadísticos de error (RMSE y MAE) e índice de concordancia ($d$) entre las series de superficie libre predicha $y$ observada para el caso C46.}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c} }
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{$t=\SI{6}{s}$}
        &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{$t=\SI{30}{s}$} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
    &   z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FE}}
        &   z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FV}}
            &   $\eta $\textsubscript{FE}
                &   $\eta$\textsubscript{FV}
                    &   z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FE}}
                        &   z\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{FV}}
                            &   $\eta$\textsubscript{FE}
                                &   $\eta$\textsubscript{FV}  \\

    \midrule
$\mathrm{RMSE}$ \[cm] & $1.2$   & $1.1$   & $1.4$   & $1.3$ & $1.2$   & $1.1$   & $1.4$   & $1.3$    \\
$ \mathrm{BSS}$ $[-]$ & $4.6$   & $5.3$   & $6.7$   & $6.6$ & $1.2$   & $1.1$   & $1.4$   & $1.3$    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: for instance if i would like to increase the width for that specific table how would that work ? im doing a similair table but with less values and the table looks very small.. which commands could i use ? thank you

Comment: @ChristianRobledo, see addendum to answer. by the way, now is time that you select which answer is best to you and accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the first column, vertical rules are always at the right hand edge, so normally you do not want `|` on the left in a multicolumn.

you have specified two lines, one at the right edge of one cell, and then one at the left edge of the next.

```
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{t=6s}
```

should be

```
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{t=6s}
```

and

```
\multicolumn{4}{|c}{t=30s}
```

should be

```
\multicolumn{4}{c}{t=30s}
```